# Python synchroniztion based on context

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a requirement where I have 2 users calling same method. I need to put some synchronization, such that request from the users should be executed sequentially. That means user1 & user2 can execute same method parallely but if user1 request consecutively, each request should get executed sequentially. Basically is there a way to synchronize based on some context?

Comment: Are you looking for a Lock? https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock

Comment: @Wolph essentially yes but based on some context or identification, which don't see in lock methods, may be i can be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

While the standard locking mechanism in Python doesn't really have context support, it's easy to extend it so it does.

```
import threading
import collections

locks = collections.defaultdict(threading.RLock)
```

And now the usage:

```
# To acquire the lock
lock_a = locks['a'].acquire()

# Do something here...

# Release the lock again
lock_a.release()
```

Comment: I was thinking on similar line, but was wondering for some established way. Do u have any other suggestion?

Comment: That depends entirely on your goal, generally I would recommend to leave this to your database server or other software. There is al lot that can go wrong with code like this so if it can be avoided, that's a good thing.